# Grid - Is there a way to filter out an empty value field?

Tags: grid

Let's say I have Grid `foo`.

Grid `foo` has three fields, `a`,`b`,`c`

The way to get all of them would be

{exp:channel:entries channel="some_channel" ...}
  {foo}
       {a},{b},{c}
  {/foo}
{/exp:channel:entries}

My question is, how do I use the `search` param for grids to filter out those fields where grid field `a` is empty?

I tried `{foo search:="=not "}` but it did not work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `a`, `b`, and `c` are columns then you should be able to do something like:

```
{foo search:a="not IS_EMPTY"}
```

Where `foo` is the name of your grid field, and `a` is the column you're searching.